# jquery function not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a registration form in html where I want to enter telephone number in a `textbox`and non numeric characters will not display while clicking non numeric keys. Here I am using jquery for this purpose but I can't get correct result.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label>Mobile No<sup style="color:#ff0000;font-size:16px;">*</sup></label>
    <input name="mobileno" type="text" id="mobileno" class="form-control" maxlength="10">                               
</div>
```

In this html already specified id attribute  as `mobileno` and my jquery is

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mobileno').keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                var key = e.keyCode;
                var ret = ((key == 8) || (key == 9) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))
                if (!ret) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                $(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
            }
        });
        $("#mobileno").bind("paste", function(e) {
            return false;
        });
        $("#mobileno").bind("drop", function(e) {
            return false;
        });
    }); 
< /script>
```

But this function can not executed...Please help me to find a solution..Thanks to all in advance

Comment: You have missed semicolon in your javascript after `var ret = ( ... (key >= 96 && key <= 105))` line.

Comment: @Alexander- thanks...but I can't execute jquery function keydown()

Comment: This line has been placed inside `keydown()` handler. It is possible to cause of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use below code to prevent non numeric characters.**

```
$("#mobileno").keydown(function (e) {

    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/awkbng0w/731/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mobileno').keydown(validateNumber);
    $("#mobileno").bind("drop", function (e) {
            return false;
        });
      $("#mobileno").bind("paste", function (e) {
            return false;
        });
});

function validateNumber(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    var ret = ((key == 8) ||(key == 9) ||  (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key     <=      40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))
    if(!ret) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @ Fahadsk:thanks..but this code not working in my code igniter code

Answer (score 0):

use this it will disable all non-numeric values

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //function to validte phone number
             $('#mobileno').keypress(function(event){
               if(event.which != 8 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
                   event.preventDefault(); //stop character from entering input
               }
           });
```

Comment: include jquery library  first then put this code below